# Rails generate models with associations for existing MSSQL database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, models

I'm working on a RoR 4 app with an existing sql-server database. I'm using tinyTDS successfully to read/write to the database.  I used 'rake db:schema:dump' to generate my schema.rb.  However, I'd like to know if anyone knows of any tools that could generate the model associations present in the db?

I did find the following tools, but they are either old or buggy:

- rmre (https://github.com/bosko/rmre) ...rails 3
- Dr Nic Magic Models (http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org)

Can you suggest a better tool?

Comment: you can generate model without migration

Comment: I would not suggest doing this via tools, givne that involves the 'tool' to perfectly understand the business logic behind the associations (I presume no tool can seperate between a plain association and a join table). Better to do this by  hand, because using a tool and fixing misinterpretation might be even more work than simply doing it by hand